# webelement response for java script executor

Tags: javascript, selenium

sometimes selenium click comment is not able click on the webelement .but when we use javascript executor it is working fine  . How the webelement is responding only for javascript executor  .

Comment: Please post the code used to click the element, and describe more about how the web page is behaving.